# Concerning homotopy groups of a finite wedge of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $X$ be a finite wedge of $m$-spheres containing some circles.

Is $\pi_n (X)$ a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module, for all $n\geq 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\pi_n(X)$ is not even a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module for most values of $n$.  Indeed, if $m>1$, then $\pi_n(S^m)$ has torsion for infinitely many values of $n$.  Since each of the spheres in $X$ is a retract of $X$, this means that if any of those spheres have dimension greater than $1$, then $\pi_n(X)$ has torsion for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me what relation there is between $\pi_n (X)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module and $\pi_n (X)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module?

Comment: Um, you get $\pi_n(X)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module by just restricting the action of $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(X)$ to $\mathbb{Z}$?  I don't know what you're looking for...

Comment: Sorry, I understood now. I was wrong.   Thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am written my main question wrong. Can I here write my correct question? or I must change the question above?

Comment: I would recommend you post a new question.

Comment: Yes, I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: C.T.C. Wall in the paper "Finiteness Conditions for CW-complexes" (in the proof of Proposition 3.3, p. 67) has mentioned that for a finite wedge containing  2-spheres and 1-spheres, say X, $\pi_2 (M_{\phi},K)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module, where $M_{\phi}$ is the mapping cylinder of $\phi$ and $\phi :K\longrightarrow X$ is a map from a finite bouquet $K$ of  circles to X which induces an isomorphism of fundamental groups.

Comment: Since $\pi_2 (K)=0$ and $\pi_1 (\phi)$ is an isomorphism, so $\pi_2 (X)\cong \pi_2 (M_{\phi},K)$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. This follows that $\pi_2 (X)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module. Is it wrong?

Comment: Looks correct to me.  You can see that more directly by just thinking about the universal cover of $X$, which is a "tree" of 2-spheres.  $\pi_2(X)$ is the free abelian group on all of these 2-spheres, and $\pi_1(X)$ acts on them freely.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Hence  can I tell that this is true for all spaces which are wedge of spheres of every dimension?

Comment: What do you mean by "this"?  You can similarly conclude that $\pi_2(X)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(X)$-module, if $X$ is any wedge of spheres.

Comment: I mean is the answer to my main question of the post positive?

Comment: No?  I answered that in my original answer...

Comment: I think $\pi_n (X)$ is a free module as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (X)$-module not as $\mathbb{Z}$-module. To see this, by Wall's construction we can extend the map $\phi$ to a map $\psi :L\longrightarrow X$ so that $\pi_i (\psi)$ is an isomorphism for $i=1,2$, where $L$ is the wedge of 1-spheres and 2-spheres. By repeating the above process, we can conclude that $\pi_3 (X)\cong \pi_3 (M_{\phi},L)$ as $\mathbb{Z}K$-module.

Comment: A free $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(X)$-module is automatically a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  It's a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(X)$, and $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1(X)$ is itself a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Your proposed argument will fail because $\pi_3(L)$ may not be trivial.

Comment: You are right. For the $K$, $\pi_i (K)=0$ for $i\geq 2$, but for the $L$ is not true. I was wrong. Thank you for your exact explanation.